# How compute $\cos(5\theta)$ and $\sin(5\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to compute $\cos(5\theta)$ and $\sin(5\theta)$. I can use the formula $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ and $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+cos(a)\sin(b)$ but it's a little bit to long. Is there an other way to compute it ?

Comment: Are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: "it's a little bit to long": $\theta\to2\theta\to4\theta\to5\theta$: you will survive.

Comment: (More detail on @YvesDaoust's comment — he's suggesting using the double angle formula for the first two. Or, alternatively, use the sum formula on $\cos(\theta+\theta)$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint :**

By Moivre formula:

$$\cos(5\theta)+i\sin(5\theta)=(\cos \theta+i\sin\theta)^5.$$

Then use [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to compute $(\cos \theta+i\sin\theta)^5$ and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind that are defined by the recurrence relation:

$$
T_{0}(x)= 1, \quad T_{1}(x) = x, \quad T_{n+1}(x) = 2x \, T_{n}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)
$$
With:
$$T_{n}(x) = \cos\left( n \, \arccos(x) \right) $$
So using $x = \cos(t)$ You get:
\begin{align}
& T_{0}(cos(t)) = 1, \quad T_{1}(cos(t)) = cos(t), \\
& T_{n+1}(\cos t) = \cos ((n+1)t) = 2 \, \cos(t) \, \cos(nt) - \cos((n-1)t) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
c_2 &=c^2-s^2, \hspace{5mm} s_2=2cs \\
c_4 &= c_2^2-s_2^2 = (c^2-s^2)^2-4c^2s^2 = c^4-6c^2s^2+s^4,\\
s_4 &= 2c_2s_2 = 4cs(c^2-s^2) = 4c^3s-4cs^3. \\
c_5 &= c_4c-s_4s = (c^4-6c^2s^2+s^4)c-(4c^3s-4cs^3)s = c^5-10c^3s^2+5cs^4,\\ s_5 &= c_4s+s_4c = (c^4-6c^2s^2+s^4)s+(4c^3s-4cs^3)c = 5c^4s-10c^2s^3+s^5.
\end{align}

Comment: You're going to want to explain your symbols there.

Comment: $c$ and $s$ shouldn't be a mystery, nor the subscripts ($1$ omitted).

Comment: I could guess what they mean, but you shouldn't make us guess.